# $in Operator Issue in Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to use `$in` operator in pymongo module of python.
I have a list of id's like below:

`ids = [ObjectId('5a02ec6c3ae7b3225ed14ed0'), ObjectId('5a02ec6c3ae7b3225ed14ed2')]`

Below is my python code :

```
client = connect_mongodb()
db = client.get_default_database()
societies = db['Societies']
result = societies.find({"_id":{"$in": ids}})
print result.count() #it prints 0 showing criteria didn't match`
```

But in mongo shell if i fire below query:

`db.getCollection('Societies').find({"_id" : {$in : [ ObjectId("5a02ec6c3ae7b3225ed14ed0") ,ObjectId("5a02ec6c3ae7b3225ed14ed2")]} })`

It is giving me 2 results.
What is wrong with my python code?

Comment: Have you imported this? from bson.objectid import ObjectId

Comment: Yes, from bson.objectid import ObjectId

Comment: are you using right database here: db = client.get_default_database() where societies collection is present?

Comment: Yes I am using it

Comment: import pymongo

from bson.objectid import ObjectId
client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.test  // specify your db here
coll = db.societies
ids =[ObjectId("5a02ec6c3ae7b3225ed14ed0")]

result = coll.find({"_id":{"$in":ids}})
for doc in result:
    print(doc)                                                                                                                  this code works for me

Comment: `db = client.get_default_database()` are you sure that's fetching what you think it is? What's wrong with simply using `client['test']` or whatever the database name is where the collection actually resides? The most likely explanation for "no results" is that you are simply looking in the wrong place. So rather than rely on such a function, make sure you are specific and consistent replicating **"exactly"** the steps you use in the shell. And indeed that you are connecting to the same instance. Also `pymongo` uses `MongoClient`, so you possibly are not using `pymongo` here.